# How do I remove the seconds from a date/time string in either JavaScript or c#?

Tags: c#, javascript

I have the option of using either JavaScript or c# to accomplish this task.

I have a lot of strings in the format "10/14/2012 8:45:34 PM"
How do I remove the seconds and retain the PM like so "10/14/2012 8:45PM"?

I can't use substring because the length of the string will be different with each day and time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C#, you can do this:

```
myTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mmtt");
```

Alternatively, you can use the built in `Format Specifiers` described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).

Edit - I removed the space between `mm` and `tt` because I just noticed your post shows `8:45PM`. You can add a space between `mm` and `tt` if you want it to be `8:45 PM`.

Comment: if these strings originated from a date, this will be the best way to do it. Also, you can use DateTime.TryParseExact: http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-tryparse to parse it and then use ToString to put it back into a string.

Answer (score 3):

If the string is consistently formatted, then:

```
var s = '10/14/2012 8:45:34 PM';
s = s.replace(/:\d+ (\w\w)$/, '$1'); // 10/14/2012 8:45PM
```

I hope that is only going to be used by a very limited audience since that format will be misunderstood by the vast majority of people. A more widely understood and much less unambiguous format is:

```
2012-10-14 8:45PM
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression.

C#:

```
string d = "10/14/2012 8:45:34 PM";
d = Regex.Replace(d, @":\d\d ", String.Empty);
```

Javascript:

```
var d = "10/14/2012 8:45:34 PM";
d = d.replace(/:\d\d /, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of **Regular Expression** for string manipulation and is pretty easier.

```js
var mydate = "10/14/2012 8:45:34 PM";

var formated_date = mydate.replace(/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})\ (\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})\ (.*)/, "$1/$2/$3\ $4:$5$7");

document.write(formated_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you could try:

```
var string="10/14/2012 8:45:34 PM";
var resultArray = string.split(":");
var result = string.replace(resultArray[2],"");
```

which should work effectively in javascript. ill test it out in a second, and update this.

UPDATE:

```
var string="10/14/2012 8:45:34 PM";
var resultArray = string.split(":");
var result = string.replace(":"+resultArray[2]," ")+resultArray[2].split(" ")[1];
```

A tad yucky. but it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/x8uUW/

UPDATE using regex (i used a regex generator, so it is not as compact as it could be, by any means. but it does work: http://jsfiddle.net/x8uUW/1/

Comment: maybe you can use regex to replace the last :NN with blank. but i think its always better to handle these at the source instead of hacking it up.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `ToString()` in Axure JavaScript for setting text of widgets, but failed, and regex in Axure is out of the question (at least, at the time I posted this), so I had figured out another simple alternative, but inefficient method of doing it:

```
aDate.toLocaleTimeString().replace(':'+aDate.getSeconds(),'')
```

Comment: Date.prototype.toShortTimeNoSeconds = function () {
    return this.toLocaleTimeString().replace(':' + this.getSeconds(), '');
}   // Usage: new Date().toShortTimeNoSeconds();